# Find bi-directional matching IDs

Tags: python

My input file,

```
ID1 ID2 value
ID3 ID6 value  
ID2 ID1 value
ID4 ID5 value
ID6 ID5 value
ID5 ID4 value
ID7 ID2 value
```

Desired output, file1.txt

```
ID1 ID2 value   ID2 ID1 value
ID4 ID5 value   ID5 ID4 value
```

file2.txt

```
ID3 ID6 value   
ID6 ID5 value
ID7 ID2 value
```

I am trying to get bi-dicrectional best matches. if have an ID1 that has a hit ID2, ID2 also has as a hit ID1, print in file1, otherwise in file2. What I tried to do is to create a copy of the input file and create a dictionary.But this gives outputs without the values (10 columns). How to modify it?

```
fileA = open("input.txt",'r')
fileB = open("input_copy.txt",'r')
output = open("out.txt",'w')

dictA = dict()
for line1 in fileA:
    new_list=line1.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
    query=new_list[0]
    subject=new_list[1]
    dictA[query] = subject
dictB = dict()
for line1 in fileB:
    new_list=line1.rstrip('\n').split('\t')
    query=new_list[0]
    subject=new_list[1]
    dictB[query] = subject
SharedPairs ={}
NotSharedPairs ={}
for id1 in dictA.keys():
    value1=dictA[id1]
    if value1 in dictB.keys():
        if id1 == dictB[value1]:
            SharedPairs[value1] = id1
        else:
            NotSharedPairs[value1] = id1
for key in SharedPairs.keys():
    ine = key +'\t' + SharedPairs[key]+'\n'
    output.write(line)
for key in NotSharedPairs.keys():
    line = key +'\t' + NotSharedPairs[key]+'\n'
    output2.write(line)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `set`s to solve it easily:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# ordered pairs (ID1, ID2)
oset = set()
# reversed pairs (ID2, ID1)
rset = set()

with open('input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        first, second, val = line.strip().split()
        if first < second:
            oset.add((first, second, val,))
        else:
            # note that this reverses second and first for matching purposes
            rset.add((second, first, val,))

print "common: %s" % str(oset & rset)
print "diff: %s" % str(oset ^ rset)
```

Output:

```
common: set([('ID4', 'ID5', 'value'), ('ID1', 'ID2', 'value')])
diff: set([('ID3', 'ID6', 'value'), ('ID5', 'ID6', 'value'), ('ID2', 'ID7', 'value')])
```

It doesn't handle pairs with `(ID1, ID1)` but you could add it to a third set and do what you decide with it.

Comment: I have filtered those IDs. You could modify the script as saving to txt file in tab format, bcos I have thousands of IDs. Many thanks anyway

Comment: Use the `csv` module.

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
data = csv.reader(open('data.tsv'), delimiter='\t')
id_list = []
for item in data:
    (x, y, val) = item
    id_list.append((x, y, val))

file1 = [item for item in id_list if (item[1], item[0], item[2]) in id_list]
file2 = [item for item in id_list if (item[1], item[0], item[2]) not in id_list]
print file1
print file2
```